# How to Show UI Image Background (Canvas) in Front GameObject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I' m new in Unity development, and I'm currently developing a memory card game, but I want to put a image background inside canvas where my grid buttons (this is like a card) are. But the image only stay in front buttons. And the buttons aren't show.

Answer (score 1):

Official documentation of Unity :

> Draw order of elements
>
> UI elements in the Canvas are drawn in the same order they appear in the Hierarchy. The first child is drawn first, the second child next, and so on. If two UI elements overlap, the later one will appear on top of the earlier one.
>
> **To change which element appear on top of other elements, simply reorder the elements in the Hierarchy by dragging them**. The order can also be controlled from scripting by using these methods on the Transform component: SetAsFirstSibling, SetAsLastSibling, and SetSiblingIndex.

*Source : [https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UICanvas.html](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UICanvas.html_)*

If you are working with Canvas set as "Screen Space", you can add a new canvas with your background and play with the `renderOrder` parameter : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Canvas-renderOrder.html

Comment: In the `RectTransform` component of the background, click the AnchorPresets icons (top left), hold ALT and SHIFT, and click on the bottom right image with the blue "expand" icon.

Comment: @ Hellium, now the buttons are appearing in front of the background, but there is a transparent layer in front of the background how to remove it?

Comment: You may have an other layer over it or an opacity problem somewhere.

Comment: I have only Canvas. Inside it I have a grid with some buttons as show in image 8 buttons, and a image as background. But I don't know why opacity in front my background.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how you linked the button and the image gameobject together I'll guess based on the most common problem:

Either - in the hierarchy put the button under the image

Or - set the button as a child of the image gameobject